# Sinon stub doesn't return value when new is used

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, sinon, chai

My code:

```
const stub = sinon.stub().returns('a value');
console.log(stub()); // 'a value'
console.log(new stub()) // functionStub {}
```

I want to check `stub.calledWithNew` but also need the stub to return the value I pass so that my test is complete.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in Sinon. The language allows returning values when using `new` and so should Sinon. Please report this on the issue tracker: https://github.com/sinonjs/sinon/issues